# Laravel :the size of app.js is 2.6M ,what should to do to it in production environments?

Tags: node.js, laravel

There are these packages in `package.json`：

```
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.4.2"
},
"dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "bowser": "^1.7.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^6.6.9",
    "vue-image-crop-upload": "^2.0.2",
    "element-ui": "^1.4.2"
}
```

After running `npm run dev`, the size of `app.js` is 2.6M , what should to do to it in production environments.

Comment: For production you would run `npm run production`. When you do that, how large is `app.js`? 

I'm guessing it will still be fairly large. If you can, reevaluate your dependencies. 

For example, do you really need jQuery? If you're doing simple DOM querying then you can do this easily with vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: If OP has sourcemaps enabled, that can take up a LOT of space, so it may not be all that big.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, building for production (using `npm run production`) will typically include minifying the JS and won't include sourcemaps, so that will save a lot of space.

There may also be scope for trimming unwanted library components. Lodash allows you to import components individually, so you can just pick the ones you need. That could save some space.

You may also choose to separate out the Javascript for different parts of your web app if it's particularly large.

Finally, if you're doing it right the JS won't be downloaded on every request. You should cache the file for as long as possible and use versioning in Mix to handle breaking changes.

Comment: If you intend to make frequent updates to your application's JavaScript, you should consider extracting all of your vendor libraries into their own file. This way, a change to your application code will not affect the caching of your large *vendor.js* file. More: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix#vendor-extraction